# PHP-SQL array structure

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble understanding two dimensional php arrays,
In my database I have a table that stores URLs, it's related to another table that stores tags by a 1 to N relation, the tables look like this:

```
URL         
ID    --->  URL_ID
            ID
            TAG
```

I'm trying to fetch this structure and store it in a PHP class, but as i do not understand

```
class Url extends databaseobject{

    $list = [

        "url" =>,
        "tags" => []


    ];
                                }
```

Can someone help me build the correct structure to store my database?

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this

```
   db_url           db_tags
id  url         id  url_id  tag
 |---------------------|
```

```
class UrlTags
{
    public $url_id;
    public $url;
    public $tags = array();
}
```

So when you need to save list of URLs with their corresponding tags.

```
$url_tags = new UrlTags();

$url_tags->$id = 1;
$url_tags->$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$url_tags->$tags[0] = 'zero';
$url_tags->$tags[1] = 'one';
$url_tags->$tags[2] = 'two';
```

**or with much more Object Oriented style:**

```
class Url
{
    public $url_id;
    public $url;
    public $tags = array();
}

class Tags
{
    public $tag_id;
    public $tag_name;
}

$url_list = new Url();

$url_list->$id = 1;
$url_list->$url = 'http://www.example.com';

$tag = new Tags();
$tag->$tag_id = 1;
$tag->$tag_name = 'one';

//Now store the tags
$url_list->$tags[0] = $tag;

$tag = new Tags();
$tag->$tag_id = 2;
$tag->$tag_name = 'two';

$url_list->$tags[1] = $tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the structure

```
$list  = array(
          1 => array(
            'URL_ID' => 1
            'ID' => 1
            'TAG' => 'hiiiii'
          ),  
          2 => array(
            'URL_ID' => 1
            'ID' => 2
            'TAG' => 'hello'
          ),
       );
```

Comment: each url has several tags, does this mean, tag => would also be an array? I  need to fill it dinamically after a mysql query

Comment: I think the response $list is an array of all of the "tag" records, with a reference to which URL it belongs to. I assume there would be a second array, $URL_List = array(1 => "http://someUrl", 2 => "http://someOtherUrl") ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are are iterating over a result set in which the two tables are joined, so each row in the result set looks something like this:

```
url, url_id, tag, tag_id
```

Also assuming that whatever adaptor you're using creates some kind of iteratable result set, then as you iterate (this is kind of pseudo-codey without knowing what adapter you're using):

```
$list = array();
while($arr = $your_adapter's_current_row){
    if(empty($list[$arr[$url_id]]) {
        $list = array(
            'URL_ID' => $url_id,
            'URL' => $url,  
            'TAGS' => array()
        }
        $list[$arr[$url_id]]['TAGS'][$tag_id] = $tag;
}
```

You can then add the array as a property of your class.